# Pinning a specific Launcher to the Windows Start Menu

Tags: install4j

I am using Install4j Multi-Platform Edition 6.0 (build 6030) to create an installation project for my application that include 2 launchers: C360.exe and C360nb.exe.

When I run the run the installation program build by Install4J, one of the installation wizard windows asks "Create shortcuts for all users".  I would like to know, how Install4J determines which launcher is used to create the shortcut. This is the shortcut that appears when you hit the Windows "Start" button.  The created "Program Group" contains both launchers plus the uninstall option as expected.

Thanks.

Comment: How is your tag related to your question?

Comment: I am using the Install4J tool to build the installer.  My question is related to the way Install4J determines how to pin the default installers to the Windows Start Menu.  Did I use the wrong tag?

Comment: I suggest to edit the questions and provide some details. When I read it, I thought that you only want to pin manually some programs in Windows.

Comment: Please include some code or other indication of how your project is pinning the items. Right now, any answer would be a guess.

Comment: I updated my questions.  The "pinning" is done by the Install4J tool, so I don't really have code to share.  I use their GUI to build the install project.

Comment: Windows 7 (start menu) or Windows 8 (metro start screen)?

Comment: This is on a Windows 7 start menu.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pin a launcher to the start menu with install4j. Windows does not provide an API for this and it would be very unusual if an application tried to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could try bundling the scripts described [here](http://blog.crayon.no/blogs/janegil/archive/2010/02/26/pin-and-unpin-applications-from-the-taskbar-and-start-menu-using-windows-powershell.aspx) or [here](https://gist.github.com/sirlancelot/368910) and running them at the end of the install flow to pin your shortcuts.